# Dissecting URLs

Tags: php, url-routing

For the request object in my PHP application, I need to dissect the URL and assign its components to class attributes (module, controller, method and the rest are parameters). Currently, I'm doing it like the following but that looks ugly to me. Are there any better ways?

```
$urlComponents = explode('/', $requestUrl);

if(isset($urlComponents[0]))
{
    $this->_module = array_shift($urlComponents);

    if(isset($urlComponents[0]))
    {
        $this->_controller = array_shift($urlComponents);

        if(isset($urlComponents[0]))
        {
            $this->_method = array_shift($urlComponents);

            if(isset($urlComponents[0]))
            {
                $this->_params = $urlComponents;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your title should indicate what the code does, the with to improve on the code is implied by posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no need to use `array_shift` like you are doing. You can just access elements of an array like this: `urlComponents[1]`, which is a lot easier to read. With this, your code would look like this:

```
$urlComponents = explode('/', $requestUrl);
if(isset($urlComponents[0])) {
    $this->_module = $urlComponents[0];
}
if(isset($urlComponents[1])) {
    $this->_controller = $urlComponents[1];
}
if(isset($urlComponents[2])) {
    $this->_method = $urlComponents[2];
}
$this->_params = array_slice($urlComponents, 3);
```

Although I would assume that a module, controller, and method *must* be given, so I would probably write it like this:

```
$urlComponents = explode('/', $requestUrl);

if (count($urlComponents) < 3) {
    throw new Exception('Cannot call method because of missing values for url: ' . $requestUrl);
}

$this->_module = $urlComponents[0];
$this->_controller = $urlComponents[1];
$this->_method = $urlComponents[2];
$this->_params = array_slice($urlComponents, 3);
```

Also note that you probably want to remove a trailing slash from the `$requestUrl` first to avoid getting empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative implementation. This seems to be more readable to me, by using `list()` to define `$module`,`$controller`, and `$method`. In the end its a matter of personal style, but i think the following provides a logical approach to how you would ideally like to layout your code for matching a route in a MVC application.

```
$urlComponents = explode('/', $requestUrl);

if(count($urlComponents) > 3){

    list($module,$controller,$method) = array_slice($urlComponents,0,3); // simply listing out the parameters seems fine to me here.

    $params = array_slice($urlComponents,3); // we know that params is anything after the 3rd index(0 based)

    $c= '\\'.$module.'\\'.$controller; // assuming module is the namespace.

    $response = call_user_func_array([(new $c),$method],$params); // assuming your controller methods return a response, instead of just echoing it.

}else{

    throw new Exception('Cannot call method because of missing values for url: ' . $requestUrl);

}
```